Intel's MKL cblas_sgemv crashes with big matrices
I want to use Intel's oneAPI Math Kernel Library to perform a matrix-vector multiplication. This is the function I ended up making:
// computes A * x + b
std::vector<float> multiplyMatrixVector(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& A, const std::vector<float>& x, const std::vector<float>& b) {

    int rows = A.size();
    int cols = A[0].size();

    // mkl_malloc to allocate aligned data
    float* newA = (float*)mkl_malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(float), 64);
    float* newX = (float*)mkl_malloc(cols * sizeof(float), 64); std::memcpy(newX, &x[0], cols * sizeof(float));
    float* newB = (float*)mkl_malloc(rows * sizeof(float), 64); std::memcpy(newB, &b[0], rows * sizeof(float));

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        std::memcpy(&newA[i * cols], &A[i][0], cols * sizeof(float));
    }

    cblas_sgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, rows, cols, 1.0f, newA, cols, newX, 1, 1.0f, newB, 1);

    std::vector<float> result(newB, newB + rows);

    mkl_free(newA);
    mkl_free(newX);
    mkl_free(newB);

    return result;
}

and I tested it like so:
std::vector<std::vector<float>> A(N, std::vector<float>(N, 1.0f));
std::vector<float> x(N, 1.0f);
std::vector<float> b(N, 0.5f);
std::vector<float> result = multiplyMatrixVector(A, x, b);

Now until N = 127, everything works correctly, but for any values above it, the program just crashes, with no apparent reason. I tried running my program in debug mode with gdb, and this is what I got:

Apparently there's an error with deallocation, because the error comes from mkl_serv_mkl_free, but I have no clue what's causing it. The fact my code works untill N = 128 tells me probably the problem is not in my code, but with something else in my system. For records, my CPU is an Intel Core i5-2400, and I'm on Windows 10. Does anybody have any clue what could be causing it or what can I try to do to fix it?
